# Rear Derailleur compatability?

Tags: derailleur-rear

---

I am replacing a broken Shimano RD-2200, and trying to find the right part.  How do I determine compatability?  The largest sprocket is 26 tooth, and the cassette is 8 speed.  Will anything by Shimano for an 8 speed work?  Or do I need to get more specific?

Comment: Generally, number of speeds and tooth range -- difference between teeth on largest cog and smallest, front + rear.

Comment: I'm about to do the same thing (replacing an 8 speed 2200 rear derailleur) and am looking at a bit of an upgrade - eg Tiagra or 105. These are advertised as '10 speed' or '11 speed' - is this a maximum? Presume they'll still work with an 8 speed cassette, as long as it's the right ratio.

Answer (score 3):

Anything from Shimano with 8 speeds should work. The problems can only start when your cassete's biggest sprocket is too big (you are well under limit).

Answer (score 0):

You can replace RD-2200 with Claris which 8 speed and compatible with large sprockets.

Comment: This is technically true, but misleading since in fact any 8-speed other than Dura Ace is compatible. Also, the question is almost old enough to go to school and there are already good answers.

Comment: The answer does also raise another question: *at the time the original question was asked*, was the answer still Claris? The original question was asked in 2013. Claris may have been considered a new group in 2014, so it's possible that it was just released when the original question was asked.